# Center Image Inserted SPD 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, css

I inserted an image in the body area but I would like to center it, I tried already "fixed width" but it is taking the ribbon and I only want to center the body area, would you happen to know any coding for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SharePoint designer, select the image and click the "center" button in the Paragraph section of the Home ribbon. That may not work depending on how your image was inserted, so the alternative is to find the image in the code view (shortcut: use the split view and select the image in design view window to get it selected in the code view window). Wrap the `<img src=... />` with `<span style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">` and `</span>`.

Comment: Thanks for that Aron, I added the code like this:
<img alt="Home" src="..." width="1134" height="1134" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" /></div>
</span>
but still not working, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to add, I hide quick launch menu, left menu and all that, I only have the body I did what you told me but still, the image is to the left

Comment: @DoMoreCarlos Try `<span style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"><img alt="Home" src="..." width="1134" height="1134"  /></span>` If that doesn't work, you'll need to find the `div` that covers the section you want it centered within, then make it like `<div ...><span style=...>` *your image and other stuff* `</span></div>`. You might also want to [learn a little about CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/), since CSS is handy to know for problems like this.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I figured it out just like that, I changed it the margin left 100px and it worked perfect, thanks  again Aron!

Comment: @DoMoreCarlos Note that your solution won't work if the browser window is made smaller or if someone has a low resolution monitor. If that isn't a problem for you, then I'm glad you got it working! Be sure to mark as answer if you think I answered your question.

Comment: I did not think of that....let try what you suggest!

Comment: Aron again thanks: This is what I am doing and it is not working
</div><span style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
<img alt="HomePage" src="..." width="1134" height="1134"></span></div>
am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Check out some tutorials on centering things with css: [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp) and [here](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html). You may have to manually set the containing division's width to 100% so that your image is centered on the whole page. Depending on your browser, you can also access built in "developer tools" with F12 (IE) or Ctrl+Shift+i (Chrome, Firefox). That'll let you see how/why things are getting rendered. It's possible you're centering your image within a division that's only as large as your image. Find the right div to center in.